# Understanding Runtimes in plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, runtime, plupload

I understand that PlUpload supports several runtimes (html5, html4, gears, flash, etc).
But most browsers now a days support flash. And most other file uploaders (namely: uploadify, fancy upload, to name afew) would function via a combination of javascript and flash. And the same file uploaders only support ONE runtime, which is flash. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Even if the flash player plugin is not installed. A developer can easily integrate flash detection tools and redirect users to a download link. Which is most common for several sites.

Which brings me to the question. Why the need to include any other runtime in pluploader, when flash is enough?

Comment: The more end users it works for, the better. If there is a user out there that has Silverlight but not Flash, then the Silverlight support will make Plupload work for yet another end user.

Comment: But what's wrong with a popup box, informing the user that the user is missing a plugin and flash needs to be installed. Most sites do it this way

Comment: Why show a popup and require an install if it can be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not always an option.  I have users in corporate environments who cannot install software on their machines and are stuck in older browser versions.  Plupload allows me to add functionality to my site for most users without sacrificing users who cannot install Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Why we have other runtimes in Plupload is the fact that Flash upload is very buggy. For example it can't chunk files and retain proper progress, it doesn't send cookie/session information by default and it has various problems with SSL. Silverlight on the other hands can load part of a file and send it without any problems with missing progress or cookies. So we tend to recommend having that as a fallback before flash to get better results however the install base for Silverlight is far less than Flash.

Comment: Interesting point, however I notice most uploaders still use flash nonetheless. Even prompting the user to install flash if it isn't already installed. Take Fancy Upload, for example.